# I cannot orderBy bool

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

I have `IList<Gu> gu= Context.GuSet.OrderBy(gu=>gu.IsSth)` where `IsSth` is a `boolean`. I want that thoose with true are listed before. But it orders by Id consequently

Comment: 0 comes before 1, so if you want true before, you need `OrderByDescending`

Comment: yes also tried descending @CamiloTerevinto but the general problem is that it does not sort in any way

Comment: Use the answer by @JonnyRaa in the duplicate. It's likely EF cannot translate that

Comment: does also not work :(